# Grouping by Column and separate by semi-colons

Tags: r

Using R I'm trying to take common items from the Name Column and then group by that column and aggregate another column by semi-colons in a single row. I'd like to this for the column identified as FA.

**From this:**

```
Name            FAs   DS
Apple 21        180   A
Apple 21        190   D
Apple 21        100   A
Apple 11        130   A
Apple 11        110   A
```

**To this:**

```
 Name           FAs             DS
 Apple 21       180; 190;100    A
 Apple 11       130;110         D
```

Comment: how comes apple 11 has D in the DS column and apple 21 has A?

Comment: `aggregate(FAs~Name, df1, paste, collapse = ";")` where df1 is your dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for `FAs` as no clear direction is given about `DS`. This is similar to the awesome `base R` solution by @Onyambu but uses `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Apple 21", "Apple 21", "Apple 21", "Apple 11", 
"Apple 11"), FAs = c(180L, 190L, 100L, 130L, 110L), DS = c("A", 
"D", "A", "A", "A")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")

#Code
df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise(FA=paste0(FAs,collapse = ';'))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Name     FA         
  <chr>    <chr>      
1 Apple 11 130;110    
2 Apple 21 180;190;100
```